# Parametrizing a surface with a single parameter.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, parametrization

Let $S=\{(x,y,z)\in \Bbb R^3: x^2+y^2=z^2 \wedge 0\leq z\leq 4\}$.

I'd like to create a function $\vec \Sigma:A\subseteq \Bbb R\to \Bbb R^3/\vec \Sigma(t)=(x(t),y(t),z(t))$ and $\text{Im}(\vec\Sigma)=S$.

I know such a function exists because $|\Bbb R|=|S|$, and I also believe that this function must be discontinuous, but either way I'd like to find it.

How could I do this?

Comment: a key word is *space filling curve*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this continuously if you don't insist your mapping be a bijection: Let $c:[0, 1] \to [0, 1] \times [0, 1]$ denote your favorite continuous surjection, write $c(t) = \bigl(u(t), v(t)\bigr)$, and define
$$
\Sigma(t) = \bigl(4u(t) \cos 2\pi v(t), 4u(t) \sin 2\pi v(t), 4u(t)\bigr).
$$

Comment: Could you add the concrete example? Why does this work/How did you come up with it?

Comment: It's difficult to be explicit about [the mapping $c$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve), see also janmarqz's comment. The constructions of area-filling curves I know are recursive and existential. But once you've got a map onto the unit square, the rest is easy: Do affine scaling to get $[0, 4] \times [0, 2\pi]$ and hit that with a polar coordinates parametrization$$(r, \theta) \mapsto (r\cos\theta, r\sin\theta, r)$$to get the upper nappe of the cone.